# Null Drawable from OnImageLoaded?

Tags: android

The app I have on the market has reported a crash within the onImageLoaded function:

```
onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable, boolean isRequestedDrawable)
```

The line it has an issue with is simply:

```
bitmap_ = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
                              drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The error is a Null Pointer Exception. The line/function works splendidly for me and many of my friends. It even works for a friend without a profile pic (it is loading a person's Google+ profile pic). Seeing as there is a default drawable if the requested one is not available, under what conditions can this possibly be NULL? Bitmap can't be null and Config can't be null lest the code never work, so clearly it's the drawable that's null. What gives?

The trace prior to the null exception pointing out the above line is as follows. It looks potentially pertinent given the "Unknown Source" references. Do I simply need to check for null and call it good? Or am I doing something wrong prior to this that can make it null to begin with?

```
at com.google.android.gms.common.images.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.images.a.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$f.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$f.run(Unknown Source)
```